# Gridview Column Width in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking to set the width of several columns to 0px initially and then controlling the width with jQuery when the table is rendered based on some user interaction on the front-end.

So far, I have

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Col1" HeaderText="col1" >
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="0px" />
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="0px />
</asp:BoundField>
```

but for some reason, the column is still showing. Why? Its width is set at 0px??

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of looking here, start with the actual html that was rendered.    Post a copy of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CSS to control width.

Inline:

`<div style="width:0px;"></div>`

Or defining a CSS class:

`<div class="zero-width"></div>`

But for what you're doing, I would go with the `Visible` property.

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Col1" HeaderText="col1" Visible="false">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
<Columns>
```

But to assign a CSS class to your `<asp:BoundField>`:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Col1" HeaderText="col1">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="zero-width" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="zero-width" />
  </asp:BoundField>
<Columns>
```